# change value of struct inside a struct

Tags: struct, c99

The secondexample below is what I would like to achieve in the firstcode written up. I want to ask how many 'dati' wants to insert then I have to do a malloc and I want to ask and save each dato of every struct so, firstly cdfM of the struct maestra and so on... How can I do that? How should I create the array with the malloc and how what should I do to save all the infos?
thx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 30

struct dati{
    struct maestra{
        char cdfM[MAX];
        char nomeM[MAX];
        char cognomeM[MAX];
        char specializzazioneM[MAX];
    }
    struct classe{
        int id;
        char nome[MAX];
        char colore[MAX];
    }
    struct insegnamento{
        int idclasseI;
        char cfmaestra[MAX];
    }
    struct bambino{
        char cdfB[MAX];
        char nomeB[MAX];
        char cognomeB[MAX];
        char dataNascita[MAX];
        int idclasseB;
        char dataIscrizione[MAX];
    }
}

int main () {

    struct dati *p,*q,*r,*s;
    struct maestra **p;
    struct classe **q;
    struct insegnamento **r;
    struct bambino **s;



    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 30

struct studente{

    char nomeCognome[MAX];
    int numeroMatricola;
    float percentualeEP;

};

int main() {

    struct studente *p;

    int m, i;

    printf("Quanti studenti devi inserire: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    p = malloc(m*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i < m; i++){
        printf("Inserisci i dati dell'utente numero %d\n",i+1);
        printf("Inserisci il nome cognome: \n");
        scanf(" ");
        fgets((p+i)->nomeCognome, MAX, stdin);
        printf("Inserisci la matricola: \n");
        scanf("%d",&(p+i)->numeroMatricola);
        printf("Inserisci la percentuale di esami passati: \n");
        scanf("%f", &(p+i)->percentualeEP);
    }
```